# C++ Algorithm Prediction, need to predict 3 numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, machine-learning, prediction

let's go straight to the facts.

I am studying for my own interest an eventual prediction algorithm for some unexistent lottery.

Let's say they roll out 3 numbers every day.

And those numbers are in range from 0 to 50.

I am asking, what would be the best approach to try to predict next 3 numbers knowing
all previous historic ones?

**1. What i have**

I have a list of 3 numbers from a range of {0,50} (integers)

```
<x0,y0,z0> 
<x1,y1,z1>
<x2,y2,z2> 
<x3,y3,z3>
```

Those numbers represent winning values of lottery.

**2. What i need**

I need to predict next 3 lottery numbers(possible WINNERS) by taking previous numbers into consideration

The order of the predicted numbers doesn't mater. It might be 1,2,3 or 3,2,1.

**3. Question**

Which approach / algorithm should i choose and why?

Super thanks for any help!

Comment: Nothing yet, just preparing myself to dive into it as i got interested in this when one of my coll. told me that this is impossible.

Comment: I miss a point... do you remove the numbers after the extraction? Other ways the probability of the extraction is completely independent from previous extraction history as in a lottery extraction numbers are uncorrelated. (Probability theory).

Comment: @Yavar, i need to predict next 3 numbers that are possible winners in next lottery. The order of the predicted numbers doesn't matter, it might be 1,2,3 or 3,2,1.

Comment: You will need some assumptions on the correlation between the numbers. Because in general, lacking any knowledge, one would model this by assuming that the numbers are random so then no matter how much previous data you have, the best prediction would be drawing three random numbers. Of course, even the best of random number generators are not completely random so chances are you may find some pattern. But perhaps your question is best posed on the math exchange instead.

Comment: If there was such "best approach", a lot of people would win the lottery everyday.. Anyway - you can try with making statistics for each "iteration" and always "predict" the numbers, that are present at most. But that's a shot in the dark and that would depend **very, very much** at the random number generator.

Comment: Is there any properties known about how the numbers are generated? I assume they are not independent, since history won't help you than, but is the order of the numbers in the list of 3 matter?

Comment: @Mkirci, no order doesn't matter and those 3 numbers are totally independent, they're are taken out of the box.

Comment: Assuming there's some correlation between the numbers, there are many, many ways of doing this (i.e. the question is too broad) - to name a few - one of many artificial intelligence techniques, statistical analysis, mapping the numbers to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers you roll out are random, there is no way to make a prediction, as the next numbers are not linked in any way to the previous one. The most you can do is a guessing algorithm.

Comment: That's no good, i was hoping at least some statistical approach could be implemented to get 'closer' to eventual win.

Comment: You can count how often some numbers occur, compared to others, and choose them more often than ones that occur less frequent, but this provides no guarantee. Actually, the chances are still pretty low.

Comment: @PeeS You can't.  Each lottery drawing is an independent event, on which previous drawings have no effect.  If the lottery is fair, here is no algorithm that can do better than simply picking three random numbers.  (There could be slight physical imperfections in the arrangement which make some numbers more likely than others.  Any honest lottery will take enough precautions against this, however, that the differences will fall beneath the threshold of measurability.)

Comment: @Paul92 Something like this was actually done for roulette in Las Vegas.  On any physical device, there will be slight physical imperfections which cause some numbers to be more likely.  In the case of roulette, if you do the statistics over a couple of weeks, you have thousands of samples, so small differences can be significant, and the house take is only about 3%, so just finding a 3% variation is a win.  In the case of a lottery, it would be rare to have more than a 100 samples, and the house take is something between 40% and 60%, so you have no chance.